# Can't use 'redux' after long break with project

Tags: npm, webpack, redux

I have an React/Redux project which I left unattended for few months. After that, when restarting with npm start I receive errors:

> Module '"redux"' has no exported member ___.
> (and here there is one of: "combineReducers", "bindActionCreators", "AnyAction")

Besides, when I hover over `redux` in import statements it shows me a path to existing folder `src/redux` (with reducers etc) and not `redux` in `node_modules`. I have checked that `redux` folder in `node_modules` actually exists and its content looks like content in similar app.

I am sure I have not midified Webpack, I practically do not know how it works.

What I have done so far is I have uninstalled and installed again redux, but it has not helped (btw uninstalling has not removed redux from node modules). Has anybody an idea how to solve that?

Here is my ts.config

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "webworker", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "paths": {
            "types/*": ["types/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["src"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a folder `src/redux`, it looks like Webpack is trying to import redux from this `src/redux` folder instead of `node_modules/redux`.

What you can try is either:

- Name your folders in src such that they don't conflict with the package names you are using. In this case, maybe rename `redux` folder to something else e.g. `src/reduxconfig`, or
- Fix your build tool's config file e.g. `webpack.cofing` or whatever config file you are using.

I personally prefer the first option. Typically, JavaScript bundlers usually first look for a module within the src folder, if they find it, they will not look for it in `node_modules`. If an import isn't found in `src`, the bundler will look for it in `node_modules`

Comment: Do you think it would be enough if I more redux folder to - for example src/js/? I see in working app I have such the structure

Comment: Yes, I believe it will work, e.g. `src/js/redux` should be fine I guess.

Comment: Do you have a file such as `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json`? you may have module aliases set there that cause webpack to import `redux` from src.

Comment: And I think that guilty might be 'baseURL': 'src' line, it fits to what you have written before. Or "include": ["src"]. Practically not sure what these do